# sshpass & svn commit in script: Works when script run manually, fails when run with Cron

Tags: bash, github, svn, cron

I have written a Bash script that I use to automatically update certain files that I store on SourceForge and GitHub. Near the end of the file, I have two commands that Rsync the updated files to SourceForge and Svn Commit them to GitHub, respectively (before anyone asks, I have my reasons for using Svn rather than Git).

My problem is that while the script does what it needs to do when I run it manually, the line of code that commits the changes to GitHub fails with an authentication error.

I have programmed the script to output the contents of Stderr into a log file. This is the contents of that file after I run the script manually and it works:

```
auto_update_svn.bash:
17 Sep 2018 18:42 UTC
SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword"
SSHPASS read: Authentication realm: <https://github.com:443> GitHub
SSHPASS read:

SSHPASS read: Password for 'XJDHDR':
SSHPASS detected prompt. Sending password.
SSHPASS read: *
<"SSHPASS read: *" repeated another 25 times
SSHPASS read:

SSHPASS read:
```

This is what that log says after I run the script through Crontab and it fails:

```
auto_update_svn.bash:
16 Sep 2018 14:00 UTC
svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
svn: E215004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
svn: E200042: Additional errors:
svn: E120191: Error running context: The requested authentication type(s) are not supported
```

From what I can see, sshpass is not running when I run it with Cron and so Svn doesn't receive a password. Strange because a few lines earlier, I use sshpass with Rsync to send file to SouceForge and that works when the script is run through Cron. One solution I've often seen is related to the Path environment variable in Cron being limited. I fixed this in my case with this line near the top of my script but it doesn't help in my case: `PATH=$PATH:$(grep 'PATH=' /etc/environment | sed 's/^.*=// ; s/\"//g')`

This is what I have in my Crontab:

```
0 14 *   *   *        /bin/bash /home/svn/xjdhdr-random-code/Bash/auto_update_svn.bash
```

And this is the contents of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:$(sed -n '/PATH=/s/^.*=// ; s/\"//gp' '/etc/environment')

sDateTime=$(date -u +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")
{
        # Commit changes
        #   SourceForge
        sshpass -f "$HOME/sourceforge_password.txt" rsync -qcruz -e ssh --exclude=.svn '/home/svn/xjdhdr-random-code/' \
                'xjdhdr@frs.sourceforge.net:/home/frs/project/xjdhdr-random-code/'

        #   GitHub
        svn status '/home/svn/xjdhdr-random-code/' | grep ^\? | cut -c2- | while IFS='' read -r sFile
        do
                svn add "$sFile"
        done
        sshpass -v -f "$HOME/github_password.txt" svn commit --username=XJDHDR --no-auth-cache \
                -m 'Automatic update of Adblock, Bash + blocklist files' '/home/svn/xjdhdr-random-code'
} 2> '/tmp/stderr-contents-auto_update_svn.txt'

if [ -f '/tmp/stderr-contents-auto_update_svn.txt' ]
then
        errors+=$(cat '/tmp/stderr-contents-auto_update_svn.txt')
        rm -f '/tmp/stderr-contents-auto_update_svn.txt'
fi


if [ -n "$errors" ]
then
        printf 'auto_update_svn.bash:\n%s UTC\n'"$errors"'\n\n' "$sDateTime" >> '/home/error_reports_to_email.txt'
fi
```

Comment: My apologies! I've chopped out the irrelevant parts of my script. Though, if you were the one that downvoted my question, it would have been nice if you had given me some time to fix the problem before doing so.

Comment: I didn't downvote. This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: As an aside, you want to avoid the [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for the help. I managed to figure out the problem. Very well, ignore that last bit of my comment. Instead, I direct it to whoever did the downvoting.

Comment: @tripleee I have to disagree with you because my circumstances mean that this isn't a useless use of `grep`. Yes, that `svn status ...` command will still work without `grep` but I have my script redirect the stderr stream of most of the script's commands into a text file. Another script I have emails the contents of that file to me once a day (if there is anything in it). If I try use `svn add` a file that is already in my svn repository, svn prints a message to stderr along the lines of `file X is already under version control`.

Comment: Thus, if I don't use `grep` to filter the output to only new files, I'm going to end up receiving an email every day with output from stderr that aren't problems I need to fix. For the same reason, I have a few uses of the `dos2unix` program that I had to silence because they were writing data to stderr that were not bug reports.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that `grep x | sed s/y/z/` can be rephrased to `sed -n '/x/s/y/z/p'` without any need for `grep`. The link I included points out this in more detail and with more variations.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I thought you were talking about my use of `grep` in the `svn status ...` line whereas you were actually talking about the `PATH=$PATH: ...` line. So basically, this `sed` command replaces my need for `grep`: `sed -n '/PATH=/s/^.*=// ; s/\"//gp' '/etc/environment'`. Come to think of it, I think I see a useless `cat` as well.

Comment: The other thing that annoys me about the mystery person who downvoted my question is the lack of follow-up. I fixed the problem with my question that caused the downvote but in the month since then, the voter has made no effort to come back and revise their vote in light of my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the cause of my problem and solution.

First, the cause. `SSHPass` requires that the program run through it must prompt for a password, which it will then supply to the prompting program. `Svn commit`, in turn, will prompt for a password if one hasn't been supplied through a command line switch **and is running in an interactive environment**. This is why I was observing what I observed; when running the script manually, svn was running in an interactive environment. Conversely, when svn is run through Cron, it detects that the environment is *not* interactive. Hence, it does not prompt for a password and `SSHPass` can't do anything.

The solution in this case is to add the switch `--force-interactive` to svn's command. Thus, the relevant line in my script now says:

```
sshpass -v -f "$HOME/github_password.txt" svn commit --username=XJDHDR --no-auth-cache --force-interactive \
        -m 'Automatic update of Adblock, Bash + blocklist files' '/home/svn/xjdhdr-random-code'
```

Another possible solution would be to add the `--password` switch to the svn command with the password in question and avoid using `SSHPass` entirely. In my case, this wouldn't work because that would require adding the password in plain text to the script. This causes two problems for me. First, the script is accessible by every user account on the server I have this script running whereas the password file used by SSHPass is only readable by the user account that is used to execute the script. Second, this script is one of the files that is uploaded to my SourceForge and GitHub repositories.